# Group By then Aggregate

Tags: r

I am working with several large data frames and need to sort the data to the first and last entry by boat and net. My data frame looks like this:

```
Boat     Net     DateTime
Dawn     71      2014-07-10 10:10
Dawn     71      2014-07-15 11:10
Whip     71      2014-07-17 08:10
Whip     71      2014-07-29 12:36
Dawn     71      2014-08-24 14:53
Whip     71      2014-09-02 11:17
Whip     73      2014-09-14 16:24
Whip     71      2014-09-15 18:16
Whip     73      2014-09-17 20:25
```

I need the dataframe to include only the first and last entry for each net by boat. The data should looks like this:

```
Boat     Net     DateTime
Dawn     71      2014-07-10 10:10
Whip     71      2014-07-17 08:10
Dawn     71      2014-08-24 14:53
Whip     73      2014-09-14 16:24
Whip     71      2014-09-15 18:16
Whip     73      2014-09-17 20:25
```

I tried a couple of different things and got close but not quite there.

```
Head <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$Net), FUN = head, n = 1)
Tail <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$Net), FUN = tail, n = 1)
Final <- rbind(Head, Tail)
```

This worked well but does not take into account the same net number on different boats, I then tried to group by boat but got the same result:

```
Head <- df %>% group_by(Boat) %>% aggregate(df, by = list(df$Net), FUN = head, n = 1) %>% ungroup
```

Both of these functions returned the following data: (The first and last entry by net number only)

```
Boat     Net     DateTime
Dawn     71      2014-07-10 10:10
Whip     73      2014-09-14 16:24
Whip     71      2014-09-15 18:16
Whip     73      2014-09-17 20:25
```

I think I am close but can't quite get there, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the aggregate approach, you can get what you want by providing both `df$Boat` and `df$Net` to `aggregate`:

```
Head <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$Boat, df$Net), FUN = head, n = 1)
Tail <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$Boat, df$Net), FUN = tail, n = 1)
Final <- rbind(Head, Tail)
```

Since you try using dplyr's `group_by`, here's a dplyr alternative, which uses `slice` by group:

```
Final <- df %>%
  group_by(Boat, Net) %>%
  slice(c(1, n())) %>%
  ungroup()
```

(Note that `group_by` and `aggregate` don't do anything special in combination- `group_by` works only with other dplyr functions like `slice`, `summarize`, or `mutate`).

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, paste(df$Boat, df$Net, sep = "-")),
           function(a) a[c(1, NROW(a)),]))
#          Boat Net         DateTime
#Dawn-71.1 Dawn  71 2014-07-10 10:10
#Dawn-71.5 Dawn  71 2014-08-24 14:53
#Whip-71.3 Whip  71 2014-07-17 08:10
#Whip-71.8 Whip  71 2014-09-15 18:16
#Whip-73.7 Whip  73 2014-09-14 16:24
#Whip-73.9 Whip  73 2014-09-17 20:25
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Boat = c("Dawn", "Dawn", "Whip", "Whip", "Dawn", 
"Whip", "Whip", "Whip", "Whip"), Net = c(71L, 71L, 71L, 71L, 
71L, 71L, 73L, 71L, 73L), DateTime = c("2014-07-10 10:10", "2014-07-15 11:10", 
"2014-07-17 08:10", "2014-07-29 12:36", "2014-08-24 14:53", "2014-09-02 11:17", 
"2014-09-14 16:24", "2014-09-15 18:16", "2014-09-17 20:25")), .Names = c("Boat", 
"Net", "DateTime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[c(1, .N)], .(Boat, Net)]
#   Boat Net         DateTime
#1: Dawn  71 2014-07-10 10:10
#2: Dawn  71 2014-08-24 14:53
#3: Whip  71 2014-07-17 08:10
#4: Whip  71 2014-09-15 18:16
#5: Whip  73 2014-09-14 16:24
#6: Whip  73 2014-09-17 20:25
```